# Check for unused parameters in a Rails controller's action's params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, actioncontroller

Is it possible to check for parameters passed in Rails' `params` that haven't been used in an action?

For example if `params` had values for `:foo_id` and `:bar_id`, then I'd want something like

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @foo = Foo.find(params[:foo_id])
    Rails.logger.info params.unused_parameters # => [:bar_id]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can simply use `except` method in 'Hash`:

```
unused_parameters = params.except(:foo_id)
unused_parameter_keys = unused_parameters.keys
```

And `unused_parameter_keys` is the result you want

Comment: That requires me to work out which keys have been used so far.